# Why can some users below 20 reputation send requests for write access in chat rooms?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, chat

Why are some users allowed to request write access in chat rooms (Gallery Rooms) when they have below 20 reputation??

See here user requested for write access in chat room.

[image: screenshot1]

See here, the user has one reputation

[image: screenshot2]

At other times the system displays this message:

[image: screenshot3]

Why does this happen? I agree that they can not write messages but the system is doing something strange by sometimes allowing some users to send requests for write access and sometimes giving them the error message.

Comment: It probably for write access, why system sometime allow for any access to room who have reputation below 20 and sometime say different "You must have 20 reputation"....

Comment: No, you don't need 20 rep for Gallery chat rooms also to read it, there is no need of any permission to read the messages of Gallery chat rooms even if your reputation is below 20

Comment: Couldn't confirm some of my statement with my sockpuppet, so I've removed my comments for now @TGMCians.

Comment: 2 options: the system doesn't check your reputation when you request access, or the user *did* have 20+ rep at some point but lost that again because something they earned rep for was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so because I see some more users there who just join SO and sent the request for write access or any thing so.

Comment: So the conclusion then is that you can request access even if you don't yet have enough reputation to speak in a chat room.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I have attached one screenshot which saying this "You must have 20 reputation ..." to send the request for write access, so sometime system allow and sometime say different that is quiet strange

Comment: Then the user *did* have 20 points when asking. It's not *that* hard to get 20 points or more then lose that again. Have you been able to register yourself without having 20 points?

Comment: @MartijnPieters How this could be in case of any user who just join few seconds back and send the request and I noticed that all those have only one reputation at all

Comment: @MartijnPieters that should have lead to a badge or two at some point though. The user doesn't have any. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2020458/jyoti-mehndiratta-khatri

Comment: Your example is an account that has existed for over a year, and hasn't been seen in 9 months. Do you have actual examples of users that have only just joined?

Comment: @Bart: The account is still a bit of an outlier; I'd love to see a bit more evidence.

Comment: I'm still wondering if, as a 1 rep user visiting a gallery chat room, that leads to an automatically granted access request @martijn. But I haven't been able to confirm that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters see here Guys requested for write access who have below 20 reputation http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22need+20%22&user=&room=15

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14206773#14206773 <-- not enough rep example

Comment: And another example: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15399311#15399311